# camel cxf request/response

Tags: java, cxf, apache-camel

i have problem with build my own webservice based on cxf/camel.

My webservice should do something like this:

I am on **DomainA** from which i send POST data to my webservice (CXF)

my CXF code is:

```
@Path("/")
@ProduceMime({ "application/json" })
public class SSO {

    @POST
    @Path("/user")
    @ProduceMime({ "application/json" })
    public String user(@FormParam("id") String token) {


    }

}
```

My CXF code receive my ***id*** variable.

Now i want to send this variable to other url *http://localhost:8080/myWebSite* and wait for  response from the url and after get the response send it to **DomainA**

my beans.xml is:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
    xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/osgi/cxf-extension-osgi.xml" />

    <bean id="cxfSSO" class="com.esb.cxf.SSO" />
    <jaxrs:server id="sso" address="/sso">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="cxfSSO" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    </jaxrs:server>

</beans>
```

Comment: You're supposed to use `@Produces` instead of `@ProduceMime`.

Comment: That said, you don't say how the other service expects the information. Is it a REST service? SOAP? General HTTP?

Comment: The other service expects normal POST variable or if it will be easier it can be also GET. It's normal Spring website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is going to be a Spring [`RestTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html), as this hides a huge amount of the complexity that you'd otherwise have to deal with.

The [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-client-access) describes the basics, but be aware that you'll want to build the request as a `MultiValueMap<String, String>` so that it will be sent to the service as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Thanks, RestTemplate are very helpfull. I'm started to use it in Spring, but it doesn't work in cxf under FUSE ESB - application compile perfectly, bot then FUSE doesn't create webservice for it, i will try to find solution for this